# How can I initialize an array of struct with array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following code but I am having problem to initialize. How can I initialize an array of struct with array?

```
typedef struct
{
    UINT8_T ID;
    string CN;
} CU_ContractDesc;

typedef struct
{
    UINT8_T DataType;
    UINT8_T DataSize;
    string SignalName; //This used only for debugging
    UINT8_T NrCont;
    CU_ContractDesc Contracts [];
} CU_BusDesc;

CU_BusDesc BusItems[]={
     {SS_SINGLE, sizeof(single_T), "S1", 1, {{99, "GV1"}}},
     {SS_UINT32, sizeof(uint32_T), "S2", 1, {{99, "GV1"}, {1, "GV2"}}}
};
```

Comment: Corrected, it is CPP.

Comment: Plain arrays in C++ are dumb: `CU_ContractDesc Contracts[];` has to have a fixed size (e.g. `CU_ContractDesc Contracts[4];`). Since that is probably not what you want, use `std::vector<CU_ContractDesc> Contracts;` instead.

Comment: It would be useful to know how the different types are defined.

Comment: AFAIR, c++ does not allow member variables with incomplete type, not even at the end of a struct.

Comment: Since when did `C++` start using `typedef` for `struct`?

Comment: @TanveerBadar C++ does not require this but supports it to honor its heritage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your array size is fixed you must specify its size:

```
struct CU_BusDesc
{
    UINT8_T DataType;
    UINT8_T DataSize;
    string SignalName; //This used only for debugging
    UINT8_T NrCont;
    CU_ContractDesc Contracts [2];
};
```

or

```
struct CU_BusDesc
{
    UINT8_T DataType;
    UINT8_T DataSize;
    string SignalName; //This used only for debugging
    UINT8_T NrCont;
    std::array<CU_ContractDesc, 2> Contracts;
};

CU_BusDesc BusItems[]={
     {SS_SINGLE, sizeof(single_T), "S1", 1, {{{99, "GV1"}}}},
     {SS_UINT32, sizeof(uint32_T), "S2", 1, {{{99, "GV1"}, {1, "GV2"}}}}
};
```

note that additional braces are required for the `std::array` initialisation.

If the array isn't a fixed size you should use `std::vector`, c++ doesn't support structures with arrays with unspecified sizes:

```
struct CU_BusDesc
{
    UINT8_T DataType;
    UINT8_T DataSize;
    string SignalName; //This used only for debugging
    UINT8_T NrCont;
    std::vector<CU_ContractDesc> Contracts;
};
```

This will work with your original initialisers.